# Mean of list elements by position

Tags: r, list, mean

Let's say I have a list of numeric vectors like this:

```
lst45 <- structure(list(CanESM2 = structure(c(75172.3232265472, 68514.4574398041, 70116.8608039856, 74918.7828659058, 74355.116765213, 70350.6421344757, 67336.5649261475, 71819.5331493378, 71239.2236221314), .Names = c("layer.1", "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9")), `GFDL-ESM2M` = structure(c(74736.6871696472, 74668.9771896362, 70693.9238479614, 72538.5751586914, 68865.4270866394, 76652.1024021149, 72507.3696491241, 72044.253433609, 70758.3188240051), .Names = c("layer.1", "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9")), inmcm4 = structure(c(64797.6587924957, 70213.8876274109, 72865.955796051, 72756.7691856384, 76886.3437725067, 78064.3871330261, 70558.1268108368, 71354.149344635, 72268.3041442871), .Names = c("layer.1", "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9")), `MRI-CGCM3` = structure(c(83597.9063896179, 79029.3697322845, 83841.0448295593, 82892.550799942, 75588.5374900818, 74541.5410072327, 84481.3175567627, 74491.1396362305, 79476.2405437469), .Names = c("layer.1", "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9")), `NorESM1-M` = structure(c(77061.6410392761, 73100.7215652466, 74400.8042865753, 69916.0041610718, 71969.7732620239, 70910.7214992523, 68759.73670578, 67605.5678882599, 66542.3943050385), .Names = c("layer.1", "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9"))), .Names = c("CanESM2", "GFDL-ESM2M", "inmcm4", "MRI-CGCM3", "NorESM1-M"))

# $CanESM2
#  layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6  layer.7  layer.8  layer.9 
# 75172.32 68514.46 70116.86 74918.78 74355.12 70350.64 67336.56 71819.53 71239.22 
# 
# $`GFDL-ESM2M`
#  layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6  layer.7  layer.8  layer.9 
# 74736.69 74668.98 70693.92 72538.58 68865.43 76652.10 72507.37 72044.25 70758.32 
# 
# $inmcm4
#  layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6  layer.7  layer.8  layer.9 
# 64797.66 70213.89 72865.96 72756.77 76886.34 78064.39 70558.13 71354.15 72268.30 
# 
# $`MRI-CGCM3`
#  layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6  layer.7  layer.8  layer.9 
# 83597.91 79029.37 83841.04 82892.55 75588.54 74541.54 84481.32 74491.14 79476.24 
# 
# $`NorESM1-M`
#  layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6  layer.7  layer.8  layer.9 
# 77061.64 73100.72 74400.80 69916.00 71969.77 70910.72 68759.74 67605.57 66542.39
```

and I need to calculate the mean of all five "layer.1", all five "layer.2" and so on. The resulting object would be a vector.

What would be the best (more legible) way to do this using only native R functions?

Comment: or `rowMeans(data.frame(lst45))` if you're not column major

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be made in several ways. I'd suggest two of them. The first:

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind,lst45))
```

Here all the elements of the list are `rbind`ed together to form a `matrix` to which we can call `colMeans` to have the mean of each column.

Another way:

```
Reduce(`+`,lst45)/length(lst45)
```

The first vector of the list is summed to the second, the result to the third and so on. We finally divide for the number of elements of the list to get the means.